# In Postgresql what to pass in WHERE clause for enum type of column to select all types?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, enums

I have a table column in Postgresql which has a data type of enum type. Now I am using a query like below to select data from the table.

```
SELECT ................. FROM ............ WHERE transaction = ?::operations.transactions;
```

I am passing this query to the `PreparedStatement` object of JAVA. It works fine when I pass any of the enum type as parameter in `setString` method of the `PreparedStatement`.

Now I want to ask that is it possible to send a string as parameter to `setString` method of the `PreparedStatement` so that I can get all the enum types in the `ResultSet`?

If it is not possible with this statement, how else could I change the query to get the desired result? Or any other strategy that I could use to get the desired result?

Comment: Just remove the where clause.

Comment: But then I will not be able to filter based on the enum types which is also a requirement.

Comment: You can't implement all your use-cases with a single query. Filtering on an enum type is one use-case, implemented by one query. Not filtering at all and get everything is another use-case, implemented using another query.

Comment: @JBNizet you mean to say that I pass a different the query string without the WHERE clasue when I want to get all the enum types?

Comment: Yes. Use the query that allows getting what you need to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`any(array expression)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20944). Example:

```
create type color as enum('white', 'blue', 'green');

with the_data(a_color) as (
    values ('white'::color), ('blue'), ('green')
)

select *
from the_data
where a_color = any(array['white', 'blue']::color[]);
```

Comment: This is a lovely way to solve my problem. When I require a single type, I could pass only one type in the array and when I require all I pass all the types in the array.